# Switching class based on inputs value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This does not seem to be working when switching the values on load.

Also initially managed to get this working for 1 switch but have multiple on the page now so the toggle moves them all, how would i adjust so its done for each one?

```js
$('.switch .inactive').hide();

var switchStatus = $('.switch').next('input').val();

// 1 = disable
// 0 = enabled
if (switchStatus == '1') {
  $('.switch .active').hide();
} else {
  $('.switch .active').show();
}

$('.switch').click(function() {
  $('.inactive, .active').toggle();

  var featureStatus = $(this).find('#ProductFeatures_TP_Status').val();
  //console.log(featureStatus);
  if (featureStatus == "1") {
    $(this).find('#ProductFeatures_TP_Status').val('0');
  } else {
    $(this).find('#ProductFeatures_TP_Status').val('1');
  }

});
```

```css
.panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel-heading .status {
  float: right;
}
.panel-collapse {
  display: none;
}
.panel-collapse.open {
  display: block;
}
.panel-body .col-md-6.left {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.panel-body .col-md-6.right {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.panel-body .redactor-editor {
  min-height: 100px !important;
}
.switch {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: -4px 10px 0 -5px;
}
.switch .active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="switch ProductFeatures_TP_Status">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
  <input type="hidden" id="ProductFeatures_TP_Status" name="ProductFeatures_TP_Status" value="0">
</div>

<div class="switch ProductFeatures_TP_Status">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
  <input type="hidden" id="ProductFeatures_TP_Status1" name="ProductFeatures_TP_Status1" value="1">
</div>

<div class="switch ProductFeatures_TP_Status">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"></i>
  <input type="hidden" id="ProductFeatures_TP_Status2" name="ProductFeatures_TP_Status2" value="1">
</div>
```

Comment: I will help you but please put this in a jsfiddle

Comment: Thank Chris, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ww30q8xg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gb13r1b3/

All i did was find `'.inactive, .active'` relative to the clicked `.switch`

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.inactive, .active').toggle();

  var featureStatus = $(this).find('[id^=ProductFeatures_TP_Status]').val();
    console.log(featureStatus);
  //console.log(featureStatus);
  if (featureStatus == "1") {
    $(this).find('[id^=ProductFeatures_TP_Status]').val('0');
  } else {
    $(this).find('[id^=ProductFeatures_TP_Status]').val('1');
  }
```

EDIT: the syntax `[id^=ProductFeatures_TP_Status]` finds any id that starts with ProductFeatures_TP_Status. Once you have the clicked `.switch`, there is only one id that starts with ProductFeatures...

EDIT-2: http://jsfiddle.net/gb13r1b3/1/

EDIT-3: http://jsfiddle.net/gb13r1b3/5/

Comment: Yep that is one of them fixed, however the logic i tried to add with changing the status depending on the input value is not working... any idea son that? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ahh sorry, my bad i just added Status1 and Status2 the IDs actually change like ProductFeatures_TP_Status, ProductFeatures_PP_Status and ProductFeatures_DP_Status - is it still possible using those? Thanks again for your help mate - plus there are many other elements on the page that start with that so need to be just within the .switch container i guess.

Comment: Change the wildcard selector to a common starting string. So in your case change id^=ProductFeatures_TP_Status to id^=ProductFeatures. As long as your id's have common starting strings then you can use the wildcard selector reliably.

Comment: Ahh no worries, i cracked it. Just need it to set the class base don the values when page is loaded now.. any ideas on that? then im all done with it haha thanks again

Comment: You're making me work for this huh? Check my updated fiddle. Btw once you hide() an element you can't interact with it anymore.

Comment: Sorry, i literally just done that change to find rather than next, is there any way around so it will show the on and off buttons depending on value? as you say im hiding inactive but not sure how to get this working lol

Answer (score 0):

Given the opening sentence of your question, I assume you're open to alternative solutions so here's a pure CSS onefor you but it requires some changes to your HTML, if that's acceptable.

You'll need to change all your inputs to be checkboxes and then place labels immediately after them in your HTML, containing your FontAwesome icons.

Then, using CSS, you position the checkboxes off-screen and adjust the styling of the icons in the adjacent labels based on the `checked` status of each `input`.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#000;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;}
input{
  left:-9999px;
  position:absolute;
}
label{
  height:24px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:27px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
label>i::before{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:24px;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
input:checked+label>i::before{
  color:#090;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input id="ProductFeatures_TP_Status" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="ProductFeatures_TP_Status"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>Label 1</label>
<input checked id="ProductFeatures_TP_Status1" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="ProductFeatures_TP_Status1"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>Label 2</label>
<input checked id="ProductFeatures_TP_Status2" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="ProductFeatures_TP_Status2"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>Label 3</label>
```